# Find and replace text between two strings in R

Tags: r, regex, string-substitution

I have created some tutorials on R in some Rscripts. I need a Handout Set(HS) and a Coding Set (CS) without answers in which students can code . I need some help regex to search for the answer section in HO so I can remove it from the CS.

In the HS  I have beginning (#'YOUR_ANSWER)and end  (#'END_ANSWER) flags before/after the answers.  To create the HO set I need to replace

```
YOUR_ANSWER
As_samp2 = 36
As_samp3 = 38      
#'END_ANSWER
```

with

```
"space for answer".
```

So if my text is in a:

```
a = "#'YOUR_ANSWER
       As_samp2 = 36
       As_samp3 = 38

       #'END_ANSWER"
```

I have tried regex but there is no replacement

```
b <-gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER(.*\n*)*#'END_ANSWER", a, replace="space for answer" )
```

if I dont use regex ie just find "YOUR_ANSWER"  - the replacement works ie

```
c <-gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER", a, replace="space for answer" )
```

if I just do regex, as expected all text is substituted ie

```
d <- gsub(pattern = "(.*\n*)*", a, replace="space for answer" )
```

but the combination doesnt work.
The regex should work see:

```
https://regex101.com/r/USvzLF/1
```

So there must be some deep R magic that I'm not getting

```
    b <- gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER(.*\n*)*END_ANSWER", a, replace="space for answer" )
    c <- gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER", a, replace="space for answer" )
    d <- gsub(pattern = "(.*\n*)*", a, replace="space for answer" )
```

I expect to have replaced all between YOUR_ANSWER and END_ANSWER with space for answer
But nothing happens. Any ideas?
UPDATE now @r2evans has shown me working regex; 
The R script I am trying to change is https://pastebin.com/mnjpkUFk (ie myfile)
And the code I am using to try and change it (in a separate R script) is:
FileM <- readLines(myfile)
FileMedit <- gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER", FileM, replace="space for answer" )
FileMedit <- gsub(pattern = "YOUR_ANSWER.*END_ANSWER", FileM, replace="space for answer" ) 
writeLines(FileMedit,file = "outputfileM.R")

Comment: I am having a really tough time understanding what your current text looks like and what you wish to transform it into. Please update your question with a simplified example of "before" and "after" transformation.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://regex101.com/r/FfunIi/1

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't `gsub("#'YOUR_ANSWER.*END_ANSWER", "(space for answer)", a)` work well enough? This is effectively your `b` ... which also works for me.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for the help, but there's a problem with escape characters in R; error message is:Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""YOUR_ANSWER\s".  So things that work in Regex 101 are not working in R

Comment: Do you want to keep `#'YOUR_ANSWER` and `#'END_ANSWER` and replace the content between them?

Comment: @r2evans - well you have moved me on a bit as I agree the code does work in the string I presented.  When I translated it into changing a file, no joy.  I am going to add something to my question to clarify

Comment: Maybe if you included a little more of your document, we might be able to provide suggestions on the concept as a whole instead of fixing this one thing. (For instance, can you just set `include=params$incl` for each chunk, where `params$incl` (parameterized r-markdown) determines the mode of the printed document?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://ideone.com/NVBo4e

Comment: I hope you solved the issue in time, if not, I posted the solution tested in R.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you read your file in as a  list of character vectors** and apply a regex that expects a *single multiline text* as input.

```
> FileM
 [1] "#'Rstudio environment"                                                             "#'==="                                                                            
 [3] " "                                                                                 "#'Top Left - scripts"                                                             
 [5] "#+"                                                                                "myfirstvariable = \"Hello R\"  #press control enter with cursor on line  "        
 [7] "myfirstvariable"                                                                   "As_samp1 = 34"                                                                    
 [9] " "                                                                                 "#'practical: create variables for arsenic concentration in 2 more samples"        
[11] "#+"                                                                                "#'YOUR_ANSWER"                                                                    
[13] "As_samp2 = 36"                                                                     "As_samp3 = 38"                                                                    
[15] " "                                                                                 "#'END_ANSWER"                                                                     
[17] "#+"                                                                                "#'Bottom Left - console"                                                          
[19] "#+"                                                                                "2+2"                                                                              
[21] " "                                                                                 "#'practical: calculate average As concentration, store result in variable As_mean"
[23] "#+"                                                                                "#'YOUR_ANSWER"                                                                    
[25] "As_mean<- (As_samp1 + As_samp2 + As_samp3)/3"                                      "#'END_ANSWER"                                                                     
[27] "#+"                                                                                "#'A word on comments"                                                             
[29] "#This is a comment"                                                                "#ignore #' and #+ <br/><br/>"
```

Hence, you should join the lines before running the regex:

```
FileM <- paste(FileM, collapse="\n")
```

Then, use

```
FileMedit <- gsub("YOUR_ANSWER.*?END_ANSWER", "space for answer", FileM)
```

Now, `cat(FileMedit, collapse="\n")` shows

```
#'Rstudio environment
#'===
 
#'Top Left - scripts
#+
myfirstvariable = "Hello R"  #press control enter with cursor on line  
myfirstvariable
As_samp1 = 34
 
#'practical: create variables for arsenic concentration in 2 more samples
#+
#'space for answer
#+
#'Bottom Left - console
#+
2+2
 
#'practical: calculate average As concentration, store result in variable As_mean
#+
#'space for answer
#+
#'A word on comments
#This is a comment
#ignore #' and #+ <br/><br/>
```

Now, save it:

```
cat(FileMedit, file = "outputfileM.R")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a more specific match, you could match the first line. Then match all following lines the don't start with optional leading horizontal whitespace chars and `#'END_ANSWER` as the only text on the line.

Then match the last line and replace the match with `space for answer`

```
#'YOUR_ANSWER.*(?:\R(?!\h*#'END_ANSWER$).*)*\R\h*#'END_ANSWER$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m96lpJ/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/awAovR)

For example

```
b <-gsub(pattern = "^#'YOUR_ANSWER.*(?:\\R(?!\\h*#'END_ANSWER$).*)*\\R\\h*#'END_ANSWER$", a, replace="space for answer", per=T)
```

If you want replace what is between YOUR_ANSWER and END_ANSWER, you could use 2 caputuring groups and use those in the replacement.

```
^(#'YOUR_ANSWER.*)(?:\R(?!\h*#'END_ANSWER$).*)*(\R\h*#'END_ANSWER)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnfIlk/1/) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/1AK9zV)